# Comment lost when trying to post offline

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

A few minutes ago I disconnected my computer from my network to try and reproduce a problem for someone.  After doing so I plugged my ethernet cable back in, but stopped short of having it all the way in, and without realizing it was still not connected to the internet.  I then went and replied via comment about my observations while offline.  I didn't get an error when doing so and the enter comment textbox closed.  A few minutes later I discovered that I was not in fact actually online, and that the comment I'd tried to post on superuser had vanished into the aether because there wasn't a page refresh involved for my browser to go back to.

I'm using Win7-64, and Opera 10.62.

Comment: Have to ask. Where is the Bug?

Comment: Are you saying that you can't post to the internet while not connected to the internet? Please clarify.

Comment: The bug is that the failure to successfully post is not detected by the script.

Comment: Interesting. When I try doing this (WinXP FF 3.6.10), I didn't get an error message either, but the existing comments disappeared and the comment I typed did not appear either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like the issue had been resolved after the question was asked. I tried it in all (latest) major browsers and I always get an error popup:

[image: error popup]

Comment: So [meta-tag:status-norepro] then?

Comment: I would rather say [meta-tag:status-completed] since the java-script code in question has definitely changed since the bug was reported...